# Screen using Mac and Serial Cable

Tags: screen

I am trying to connect to my Pi via a serial cable using the following command in my Mac terminal...

```
screen /dev/tty.usbserial* 115200
```

However, I keep getting the the following errors:

```
[ 2870.290939] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #15905: comm cron: reading directory lblock 0
[ 2870.302768] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #79863: comm cron: reading directory lblock 0
[ 2870.303383] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #79650: comm systemd-journal: reading directory lblock 0
[ 2870.313898] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #15905: comm cron: reading directory lblock 0
[ 2870.325810] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #79650: comm systemd-journal: reading directory lblock 0
[ 2870.336815] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #15905: comm cron: reading directory lblock 0
[ 2870.359802] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #79650: comm systemd-journal: reading directory lblock 0
[ 2870.371877] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #79650: comm systemd-journal: reading directory lblock 0
[ 2870.383896] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #79650: comm systemd-journal: reading directory lblock 0
[ 2870.396000] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #79650: comm systemd-journal: reading directory lblock 0
```

Everything is connected properly and the image has been written to the SD card.

Does anyone have any idea where I might be going wrong? It's driving me crazy!

Cheers

Comment: Looks like your SD card is corrupted.

Comment: Would that be a case of just wiping it and burning the image again?

Comment: That is impossible to answer from the info supplied. So check the SD card in a computer other than the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Chris possibly you have a dying SD card, in which case you should purchase a new one; however, it is also possible you have a corrupted filesystem. If your filesystem is corrupted, wiping it and burning the image again should fix it. If your issues persist, or arise again, it's definitely the SD card and you should get a new one.